# Body namespace declaration in WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a soap request declared like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
>
    <soap:Body xmlns:myResource="example.org/api/soap/myResource">
        <myResource:create_resource>
            <myResource:myResourcesList>
                <myResource:myResource>
                    <myResource:title>FIRST TITLE</myResource:title>
                </myResource:myResource>
                <myResource:myResource>
                    <myResource:title>SECOND TITLE</myResource:title>
                </myResource:myResource>
            </myResource:myResourceList>
        </myResource:create_resource>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to write a WSDL file that would handle such requests. Let's say I have declared basic definitions and models:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions
    name="mySoapApi"
    targetNamespace="http://example.org/api/soap/?wsdl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsdlsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:soap12enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
    xmlns:soap12env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:tns="http://example.org/api/soap/?wsdl"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    >

    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://example.org/api/soap/?wsdl">

            <xs:complexType name="myResource">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="myResource" type="tns:myResource"/>


            <xs:complexType name="myResourceList">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="myResource" type="tns:myResource" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="myResourceList" type="tns:myResourceList"/>


            <xs:complexType name="createMyResourceListResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="myResourceList" type="tns:myResourceList"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="createMyResourceListResponse" type="tns:myResourceList"/>

        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
```

I have a few problems with this.

I don't know how to handle the namespace declared in request body tag:

```
<soap:Body xmlns:myResource="example.org/api/soap/myResource">
    <myResource:create_resource>
        <myResource:myResourcesList>
            <myResource:myResource>
                <myResource:title>FIRST TITLE</myResource:title>
            </myResource:myResource>
            <myResource:myResource>
                <myResource:title>SECOND TITLE</myResource:title>
            </myResource:myResource>
        </myResource:myResourceList>
    </myResource:create_resource>
</soap:Body>
```

I understand, that each Type and operation should be declared in proper namespace in WSDL file. How to do that? How to write WSDL file so in response for this request I would get something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
    soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
>
    <soap:Body xmlns:myResource="example.org/api/soap/myResource">
        <myResource:created_resource>
            <myResource:myResourcesList>
                <myResource:myResource>
                    <myResource:title>FIRST TITLE</myResource:title>
                </myResource:myResource>
                <myResource:myResource>
                    <myResource:title>SECOND TITLE</myResource:title>
                </myResource:myResource>
            </myResource:myResourceList>
        </myResource:created_resource>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Where the main thing is that `myResource:create_resource` is changed to `myResource:created_resource`? (let's say that the logic behind creating resources is executed correctly)